# Help in understanding this motivation for not completing the $\sigma$-algebra in the definition of measurable stochastic Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The definition 3.2.22 aluded to in the picture below is the definition of a (product space) $\mathcal{B}([0,\infty[)\times \mathcal{F} $-measurable Stochastic Process $X:[0,\infty[\times \Omega \rightarrow E$, where $(E,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space.

[image]

I'm not sure I understand the definition of $X$, and $X_{\omega}$ at the event they define in the last part of the remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is the function of two variables $(t,\omega)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$. If $T:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ (thought of as a random time) is $\mathcal F$-measurable  then you can consider the function $X_T:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ defined by $X_T(\omega)=X_{T(\omega)}(\omega)$. In the specific case at hand, $T$ is the identity function on $[0,1]$ and $X_T(\omega) = X_{\omega}(\omega) =I_{\{\omega\in V\}}$. Thus, $[X_T]^{-1}(\{1\}) =V$, which in not $\mathcal F$-measurable, so $X_T$ is not a random variable.

I guess the author's point is that even though $X$ is measurable with respect to the completion of $\mathcal B[0,1]\otimes\mathcal F$, this is not enough to guarantee that compositions like $X_T$ are random variables. On the other hand, for each fixed $t\ge 0$, $X_t(\omega)=I_{\{t=\omega\in V\}}$ vanishes for all but one $\omega$, hence a.e. Because $\mathcal F$ is complete, $X_t$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable.

Comment: Thanks for the help, John. ;)